# Why is Variable Value Assigned with Null in this PHP array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

```php
   /**
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $val
     */
    public function createAdminTask($key, $val)
    {
            $request_body = [
                "order_number" => $val,
                "order_id" => null,
                "prescription_id" => null,
                "payer_id" => null,
                "card_id" => null,
                "prescription_key" => null,
            ];

            dd($val,$request_body); }
```

I have this function with **parameter ($key,$var)** when I **return** or **dd** the **$request_body** the value of **"order_number"**  be **null** but the **$var** value returned\printed correctly here is the dd result

```php
"Y81383124932"

array:9 [▼
  "order_number" => null
  "order_id" => null
  "prescription_id" => null
  "payer_id" => null
  "card_id" => null
  "prescription_key" => null
]
```

but when **changing "order_number" position in the above code** like this

```php
            $request_body = [
                "order_id" => null,
                "prescription_id" => null,
                "payer_id" => null,
                "card_id" => null,
                "prescription_key" => null,
                "order_number" => $val,
            ];
```

the array act as normal and order_number be set with its value here is dd

```php
"Y81383124932"
array:9 [▼
  "order_id" => null
  "order_number" => "Y81383124932"
  "prescription_id" => null
  "payer_id" => null
  "card_id" => null
  "prescription_key" => null
]
```

So why this could happen, is there a cached value or something the PHP used to assign the variable to the array?

Comment: That is for sure weird. Try the php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Where and how are you calling `createAdminTask`? Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Sidenote, you have `($key, $value)`, but in the code you posted, `$key` is never being used; could that be part of your issue?

Comment: for these sort of odd issues make sure you are providing an example that can allow us to reproduce this issue.